# getting realtime data from ubidots to android app

Tags: java, android, iot

i am doing project on ecg monitoring android app so i need to get real time data from ubidots, i manage to get latest variable value when i run app but not the all new values which will be updated continuously.So, i need help to get real time data in my app as a result my app should get data when it is updated in ubidots variable .

here is my code for getting variable:

````
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private TextView ecgLevel;
String variableValue;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
ecgLevel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ecg);
ApiUbidots getApi = new ApiUbidots();
getApi.execute();
}
class ApiUbidots extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Value[]> {
private final String API_KEY = “";
private final String VARIABLE_ID = "”;
@Override
protected Value[] doInBackground(Integer... params) {
    ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(API_KEY);
    Variable ecgLevel = apiClient.getVariable(VARIABLE_ID);
    Value[] variableValues = ecgLevel.getValues();
    return variableValues;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Value[] variableValues) {
    double varValue = variableValues[0].getValue();
    variableValue = (String.valueOf(varValue));
    ecgLevel.setText(variableValue);
}
}
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Use [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) for hit the API after you get latest variable